# Mypy: How to take a Type as function argument and invoke a class method on that type

Tags: python, mypy

The issue I'm facing is best explained with the following example:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractclassmethod
from typing import Type


class SomeInterface(ABC):
    """Interface definition"""

    @abstractclassmethod
    def say_something(cls, stuff_to_say: str) -> None:
        """Some class method to be implemented"""


class TheImplementation(SomeInterface):
    """Implementation of above interface"""

    @classmethod
    def say_something(cls, stuff_to_say: str) -> None:
        """Implementation of class method in interface"""
        print(stuff_to_say)


def do_something_with_type(input_class_type: Type[SomeInterface]) -> None:
    """Function that takes a class type as argument to call `say_something` on it"""
    input_class_type.say_something("hi")


do_something_with_type(TheImplementation)
```

Note that the above code is valid Python, which executes and prints the right string "hi".

However, `mypy` shows the following errors:

```
tests/annotation_test.py:28: error: Too few arguments for "say_something" of "SomeInterface"
tests/annotation_test.py:28: error: Argument 1 to "say_something" of "SomeInterface" has incompatible type "str"; expected "SomeInterface"
```

What am I doing wrong here? From reading the documentation I sense that `input_class_type` argument to `do_something_with_type` needs to be annotated differently but am not sure how exactly to go about this.

Comment: Looks like mypy doesn't understand abstractclassmethod. What happens if you use `@classmethod` on top of `@abstractmethod` instead? ([`abstractclassmethod` is deprecated now.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractclassmethod))

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Bingo. Using `@abstractmethod` with `@classmethod` instead of `@abstractclassmethod` fixed it. Thanks a ton. Can you convert this comment to an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like mypy doesn't understand `abstractclassmethod`. Stacking `classmethod` and `abstractmethod` instead should work:

```
class SomeInterface(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def say_something(cls, stuff_to_say: str) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError
```